# How to save a GeoJSON into file using javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, geojson

I am wondering if I have a GeoJSON object such as

```
var geoJSONLoc= {
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"features": [
    {
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
            "timeReported": "2013-01-22 08:42:26+01"
        },
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [
                7.582512743,
                51.933292258,
                1
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
            "timeReported": "2013-01-22 10:00:26+01"
        },
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [
                7.602516645,
                51.94962073,
                1
            ]
        }
    }]}
```

How can I save this into a .json file for future use?

I am trying to use

```
  localStorage.setItem('geoJSONLoc.json', geoJSONLoc);
```

but it doesnt seem to be the right answer.

Comment: Are you in a browser or in node? If you are in a browser, you can only save/load from disk via a user prompt and the file dialog

Comment: I use nodejs, and trying to save value so I can have it to use for later

Comment: Ok I've added node to the tags, this changes the question quite a bit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done a little work in NodeJS, so this maybe way off base.
But couldn't you use the fs module for this?

something like

```
var fs = require('fs')
fs.writeFile('geoJSONLoc.json', geoJSONLoc, function(err){
    if(err){        
        console.log(err);
    }
});
```